# if !checklogin? then return end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to make show.html.erb(groups) pages open to visitors(,which are not users) as well.
But my code has "if !checklogin? then return end" on groups_controller, so they can't see the show.html.erb pages. I know I should remove "if ! checklogin? then return end" but have no idea how to reconstruct my code as a whole.

Could you give me some hints?

☆members_controller

```
def checklogin?
    if session[:user_id] != nil then
        return true
    else
        redirect_to '/members/login'
        return false
    end
  end
```

☆login.html.erb(members_controller)

```
      <div class="span4">
          <h4 class="title">Users' reading texts</h4>

                <% @books.each  do |book| %>   
                   <a href="/groups/<%= book.id %>" rel="tooltip" title="<%= book.name %>" target="_blank"><%= image_tag book.imageurl, :width => '30px', :height => '30px'%></a>
                <% end %>
          </div><!--span4-->
```

☆groups_controller

```
def show
 @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    @group_message = Group.find(params[:id]).group_messages.build
    if !checklogin? then return end
    @group_messages = Group.find(params[:id]).group_messages.order("created_at desc")
    @me = me?
    @member = Member.find(session[:user_id])
    @isGr = GroupInMember.where(:member_id => session[:user_id], :group_id => 
        params[:id].to_i).count > 0


   @gms = Group.find(params[:id]).group_messages.order("created_at desc").scoped
      if params[:page].present?
       @gms = @gms.where("page = ?" ,  params[:page] )
      end
      if params[:content].present?
       @gms = @gms.where("content like ?" , "%" + params[:content] + "%")
      end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @group_messages }
    end
  end
```

☆show.html.erb(groups)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
      <div id="individual"> 
        <h4>※「<%= @group.name %>」のページ</h4>
        <%= link_to image_tag(@group.imageurl, :width=>"100" ,:height=>"150"),@group.detailurl , :target => '_blank' %>
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>プロフィール</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>著者</th>
                <td><%= @group.author %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>出版年</th>
                <td><%= @group.published %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>出版社</th>
                <td><%= @group.publish %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>ページ数</th>
                <td><%= @group.page %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>ISBN</th>
                <td><%=  @group.isbn %></td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div><!--individual-->
        <%# if @group.admin %>
          <%#= link_to 'Profile Edit', edit_group_path(@group),class: "btn btn-midium btn-primary" %>
        <%# end %>  
          <hr>
   <% if session[:user_id]%>       
      <div class="group-side">
          <% if @isGr %>
              ※登録済みです。
          <% else %>
              ※登録していません。
         <% end %>
      </div>
        <p class="group-side">
        <%= link_to '本棚登録/解除', {:controller => 'groups', :action => 'join', :id =>
        @group.id }, class: "btn btn-midium btn-primary"%></p>
      </p>
      <p></p>
      <div class="group-side2"><b>この本を登録した人一覧:</b></div>
        <% @group.group_in_members.each do |m| %>
         <% @member = Member.find(m.member_id) %>
           <% if @member.provider %>
            <a href="/members/<%= m.member_id %>" rel="tooltip" title="<%= raw(@member.name) %>"><%= image_tag @member.image, :width =>'30px', :height =>'30px' %></a>
          <% elsif @member.avatar_file_name %>
            <a href="/members/<%= m.member_id %>" rel="tooltip" title="<%= raw(@member.name) %>"><%= image_tag @member.avatar.url(:thumb), :width =>'30px', :height => '30px' %></a>
          <% else %>
            <a href="/members/<%= m.member_id %>" rel="tooltip" title="<%= raw(@member.name) %>"><%= image_tag 'love.png', :width =>'30px', :height => '30px' %></a> 
          <% end %>
        <%# if GroupInMember.where( :member_id => session[:user_id], :group_id => @group.id ).length > 0 %>
        <%# end %>  
      <% end %>             
      </div>
  <% end %>
    <div class="span8">
      <p>
        <b></b>
      </p>
      <div class="post_on_group">
        <% if GroupInMember.where(:member_id =>session[:user_id], :group_id=>@group.id).length > 0 %>
          <%= form_for([@group, @group_message]) do |f| %>
                <% if @group_message.errors.any? %>
              <div id="error_explanation">
                <h2><%= pluralize(@group_message.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this group_message from being saved:</h2>
                <ul>
                <% @group_message.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                  <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
                </ul>
              </div>
            <% end %>
            <div class="field">
              <%#= f.label :member_id %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :member_id, :value => session[:user_id] %>
            </div>
             <div class="field">
              <%#= f.label :group_id %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :group_id %>
            </div>
            <div class="form_index2">
              <%#= f.label :"" %>
              <%= f.text_field :page, :class=> "span2" %>ページ（※半角数字の入力必須）
            </div>
            <div class="form_index4">
              <%#= f.label :"何行目あたり？" %>
              <%= f.text_field :line, :class=> "span1" %>行目あたり（※半角数字。入力は任意）
            </div>  
            <div class="form_index4">
              <%= f.label :"投稿内容（※必須）" %>
              <%= f.text_area :content ,:class => "span12",:size => "20x5" %>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
              <%= f.submit "投稿"%>
            </div>
          <% end %>
         <% end %> 

      </div> <!--post_on_group-->
      <div>
        ※この本に関する投稿をページ数や投稿内容から検索できます。
       </div> 
         <div class= "form_index">
              <%= form_tag({:action=>"show"}, {:method=>"get"}) do %>
               <div class="from_field_index5">
                <%= text_field_tag 'page' ,'', :class=> "span3" %>
               <%= submit_tag 'ページ'   %>
              <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>
          <div class= "form">
              <%= form_tag({:action=>"show"}, {:method=>"get"}) do %>
               <div class="from_field_index">
                <%= text_field_tag 'content' %>
               <%= submit_tag '投稿内容' %>
              <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>


      <hr>
      <br/>
      <% if @gms %>
         <% @gms.each do |gm| %>
                 <div class="message_area">
                      <div class="each_message">
                        <%= image_tag gm.group.imageurl,:width => '20', :height => '25' %>


                          <%= 'Page:' + gm.page.to_s + '＆' %><%= 'Line:' + gm.line.to_s %>
                        <a href="/members/<%= gm.member.id%>"><%= gm.member.name %></a>
                        (<%= gm.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)
                       <div class="group_message">  
                        <p class="message_content"><a href="/group_messages/<%= gm.id%>" > <%= truncate(gm.content, { :length => 300}) %></a></p>
                       </div><!--group_message-->
                       <br/>
                        <% if gm.group_message_comments.present? %>
                           <% gm.group_message_comments.order("created_at asc").each do |gmsc|%>
                            <div class="group_message_comment">
                               <p><a href="/members/<%= gmsc.member ? gmsc.member.id : "unknown" %>"><%= gmsc.member ? gmsc.member.name : "unknown" %></a>  (<%= gmsc.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)</p>
                               <%= truncate(gmsc.content, { :length => 300}) %> 
                            </div> <!--group_message_comment-->
                            <br/>
                           <% end %><!-- each do -- >
                        <% else %> 
                        <% end %> <!--if -->
                      </div><!--each_message-->
                      <br>
                 </div> <!--message_area--> 
               <% end %>   
      <% else %>
         <% @group_messages.each do |gm| %> 
                    <div class="message_area">
                        <div class="each_message">
                          <%= image_tag gm.group.imageurl,:width => '20', :height => '25' %>
                            <%= 'Page:' + gm.page.to_s + '＆' %><%= 'Line:' + gm.line.to_s %>
                          <a href="/members/<%= gm.member.id%>"><%= gm.member.name %></a>
                          (<%= gm.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)
                         <div class="group_message">  
                          <p class="message_content"><a href="/group_messages/<%= gm.id%>" > <%= truncate(gm.content, { :length => 300}) %></a></p>
                         </div><!--group_message-->
                         <br/>
                          <% if gm.group_message_comments.present? %>
                             <% gm.group_message_comments.each do |gmsc|%>
                              <div class="group_message_comment">
                                 <p><a href="/members/<%= gmsc.member ? gmsc.member.id : "unknown" %>"><%= gmsc.member ? gmsc.member.name : "unknown" %></a>  (<%= gmsc.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)</p>
                                 <%= truncate(gmsc.content, {:length =>300}) %> 
                              </div> <!--group_message_comment-->
                              <br/>
                             <% end %><!-- each do -- >
                          <% else %> 
                          <% end %> <!--if -->
                        </div><!--each_message-->
                        <br>
                   </div> <!--message_area-->
                <% end %>  <!--each do -->

      <% end %>
    </div><!--span8-->
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to check login and redirect, is by using the callback of [before_filter](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter)

```
before_filter :check_login
```

`check_login` will redirect user to login action unless redirect

```
 def check_login
     unless session[:user_id]
          flash[:error] = "You must be logged in to access this section"
          redirect_to '/members/login'
     end
 end
```

If you want to enable access just for some actions - you can exclude them:

```
before_filter :check_login, :except => [:index, :show, etc..]
```